# Smallest body that can be observed from Earth?

Tags: telescope

What is the minimum size of an object that can be observed from Earth with our most powerful telescope?

I understand that the answer depends on how far the object is from Earth. For the sake of  discussions let us consider distances less the orbit of Neptune.

Comment: About 10 cm in diameter at Low Earth Orbit. Capability for anything less is **classified**.

Comment: wow! 10cm object from LEO? Amazing

Comment: Do meteorite dust specks count? If the distance is less than Neptune, would it include objects actually on Earth?

Comment: Sathish is asking how small an object, at the distance of Neptune, can be resolved by a telescope on the earth's surface. Does anyone know what scope holds the current record for angular resolution? That and simple geometry would answer this question.

Comment: As Wayfaring Stranger says, the telescope with the lowest angular resolution can lead to the answer

Answer (score 3):

The smallest **natural** object that I know of that has been detected from an Earth-bound telescope is [2011 CQ1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_CQ1), a one-meter asteroid observed while [specifically looking for NEOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalina_Sky_Survey).

As DeerHunter mentions in a comment, smaller artificial objects are identified and tracked, mostly by [NORAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Aerospace_Defense_Command) and some other national defence centers.